# How to realize a virtual resource several times?

Tags: puppet

I have exactly the problem described here 2 years ago and I could not find any documentation about this.
http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/3809

I have to realize a virtual resource twice on the same host, and this does not seem to be possible. Is there a workaround or do I have a design issue ?

The goal is to deploy the same ssh public key for different accounts.
I declare the public key as a virtual resource

```
@ssh_authoized_key{'blah': ....}
```

And to realize it for the users and for root accounts I do :

```
Ssh_athorized_key<|tag==admin|>
Ssh_athorized_key<|tag==admin|>{ user => 'root' }
```

Only the second of the 2 statements will be realized. I tried to isolate them in different classes, but the problem is still the same.

Does someone have an idea to get me out of this ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a define instead.

```
define create_virtual_ssh_authorized_key($user, $tag) {
    @ssh_authorized_key { "$name":
        user => $user,
        tag  => $tag,
        ...
    }
}

define realize_ssh_authorized_key($tag, $user = undef) {
    if ! defined($user) {
        Ssh_authorized_key <| tag == $tag |>
    } else {
        Ssh_authorized_key <| tag == $tag |> { user => $user }
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
create_virtual_ssh_authorized_key { adminonly: user => blah, tag => admin, }
create_virtual_ssh_authorized_key { rootadmin: user => root, tag => admin, }
realize_ssh_authorized_key { adminonly: tag => admin, }
realize_ssh_authorized_key { rootadmin: tag => admin, user => root, }
```

Comment: Thank you for this idea. I tried it out.
But it does not work, the second 'realize_ssh_key' declaration will not be executed. I think that, in the end, you end up calling for the realization of a resources wich has already been realized.

Comment: You want to create two different resources, not to realize a resource twice. For that simply give it another name in the first define ` @ssh_authorized_key { "${name}-${user}":`